# window open javascript issue: access denied

Tags: javascript

the following code doesn't work (run on windows server 2008, IE8, Visual studio 2010)

```
if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(csType, csName))
            {
                StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
                csText.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");

              csText.Append("window.open('" + strCheminFile + "','','menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=600') ");

                csText.Append("</script>");
                cs.RegisterStartupScript(csType, csName, csText.ToString());
            }
```

strCheminFile contains a path file:///C:/Fichiers_Excel/CalculProcedure/procedure.xlsm

the following code is generated into aspx web page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.open('file:///C:/Fichiers_Excel/CalculProcedure/procedure.xlsm','','menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=600') </script></form>
</body>
```

the following exception is thrown by windows: Access denied.
 it seems to be a security issue with IE8.
Thanks

Comment: That's a security thing indeed. So its not possible.

Comment: It's permision problem. The ´c:/fichiers_excel´ folder has the right permisions for the IIS_USER?

Comment: The keyword here is "cross domain access"... this is blocked by browsers

Comment: that's security related. Javascript is not allowed to access local files. Because if it could, javascript could **steal** files from user machine

Comment: Deploy your file to a server and use `http://yourfile` would fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Place you xlsm file to a server and change path to it. It should resolve your problem.